# Javascript. Изменить link rel при загрузке

Tags: javascript

Сделал сайт, пытаюсь его как то оптимизировать под мобильные устройства. Сайт простой и там особо нечего менять кроме ширины в процентах, за это отвечает стиль css. Хочу сделать второй css и подключать его в зависимости от разрешения дисплея. Как мне изменить имя файла css, методом Javascript? вот строка в которой нужно изменить имя файла css

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='layout.css'>
```

Comment: не делайте так. используйте media queries — http://htmlhook.ru/adaptivnyj-veb-dizajn-s-css3-media-queries.html

Comment: да все норм теперь, помогла статья высше, типа @media screen and (min-width: 1600px)

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен что после погрузки страницы и замены имя файла в link он погрузится.
Но все же можно дать этому элементу id например `id='mobStyle'` и после через `document.getElementById('mobStyle')` найти его и заменить атрибут href на нужный файл

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  document.write(
    smth
    ? "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='layout-1.css'>"
    : "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='layout-2.css'>"
  );
</script>
```

Но вообще, так не надо делать со стилями.